# What really determines the order JavaScript modules are executed in the .html?

Tags: javascript

I read that [the module that appears first is loaded first](https://javascript.info/import-export). This wasn't true.

Before I bountied this question I learned:

1. Modules that have no imports (leaf modules) are executed first.
2. A module that imports will not execute until the module it imports from executes.

---

*This has allowed me to explain a basic scenario like this:*

`2.js` logs `2` and exports `functionTwo` (which, when called, logs `"2-export"`).
`1.js` logs `1` and imports and executes `functionTwo` from `2.js`.

No matter the source-order of these modules, `2.js` always executes first because `1.js` can't execute before `2.js` - it relies on something `2.js` exports to it. The console always reads: '2, 1, 2-export'.

---

*However it is an incomplete answer for these 2 scenarios:*

1. ModuleA imports from ModuleB. ModuleB imports from ModuleA.
2. ModuleA imports from ModuleB. ModuleC imports from ModuleD. I've been experimenting with source-order and I can't intuitively pick up the rule that determines the complete order of execution of modules. All I do know is that D or B has to execute first. (Sometimes DB or BD executes first; sometimes DC or BA executes first)

---

*P.s.*

Is it true that the ruling we're talking about only applies to modules without the `async` attribute? Is it true modules with the `async` attribute are simply executed as soon as they are loaded?

Comment: Do you mean `2.js` imports `functionExport` from `1.js`? If that's the case, then `1.js` ends up being loaded first, because `2.js` needs something from it.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi 1. Yes. 2. And what would happen if `1.js` needed something from `2.js`? I've only been learning from the page I linked in my question. Where can I see a comprehensive set of rules?

Comment: Then you'll create a circular dependency and it will cause an error because one of them **has** to be loaded before the other, so it won't find whatever it needs from the second one (because it was not loaded yet).

Comment: I've created this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/import-order-26wyf?file=/index.js) so you can see it in action and play with it.

Comment: *2.js* is still loaded first, but since it has a depenency on *1.js* it will not be executed before *1.js* has been loaded and executed as well.

Comment: You better [edit] the question and include the relevant part of the code. Post only the functions you mentioned and let their code consist only of their calls to `console.log()`.

Comment: @axiac I don't know how I can make the code any more simple

Comment: You didn't post any code.

Comment: @Bergi I've changed the question to say 'execute'. Is it correct to say though that for deferred modules that don't have imports, source order determines order of loading and order of execution?

Comment: How HTML loads and executes JavaScript is defined in [the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model) which goes over the algorithm used to load and execute scripts in painstaking detail...

Comment: I’m just looking for what determines the order of execution. I would have to comprehend that document to know the outcome of scenario 1 or 2 (as outlined at the bottom of my question?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rule is pretty simple: the leafs of the dependency trees are imported first (their code is being executed), then all of the intermediate modules up to the root modules.

That's why you observed this behavior:

- `1` is a leaf module, it's being executed first (`console.log('1')` and the `functionExport` declaration)
- `2` imports `1` so it's being executed right after (`console.log('2')`)
- `2` eventually calls the function from `1` (`console.log('1export'`)

The [ES6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0) actually doesn't detail clearly whether the imports should be processed sequentially or not. Some browsers might have sequential imports while some other browsers might not.

If you want to guarantee a certain order of execution and have a consistent behavior across browsers, you have to specify a chain of imports accordingly. Two chains of imports are not guaranteed to execute separately (that's why you see DB first sometimes, instead of DC).
Two chains of imports are not guaranteed to execute in a certain order (that's why you see sometimes DB, sometimes BD).

The only guaranteed thing is that a script executes **after** its imports have already executed.

Last word about the `async` attribute, it allows to defer the fetching and execution while the browser continues to parse the page. It applies to `module` scripts just like regular scripts, the only difference is that they also load their dependencies, to comply with the rule stated above.

Comment: Thanks for your response @GuerricP. What is the dependency tree? What is a leaf module? What makes a module a leaf module? It isn't the fact that it exports something, is it? Might need to avoid (or at least explain) the terminology and put it into simple words first, if you wouldn't mind!

Comment: We often refer to the structure generated from a chain of imports as the "dependency tree". A "leaf module" is a module that doesn't import anything, then the "branches" are a chain of imports, up to the root module (which is not imported anywhere): the trunk of the tree. It's just a simple metaphor which is actually common technical vocabulary to define a structure composed with nodes linked together.

Comment: @Guerric So where none of the modules import anything, order of loading is determined purely by source-order (the order which scripts appear on the page). As soon as a module imports something, it goes to the back of the que - or at least is no longer part of this source-order ruling. I'm afraid I'm not really understanding the tree analogy. Is this information formalised and written down somewhere?

Comment: @Guerric P.s. I should've mentioned - is it true that the ruling we're talking about applies to modules that have the `defer` attribute without the `async` attribute. Is it the case that modules with the `async` attribute are simply loaded as soon as they can and none of this ruling we're talking about applies to them?

Comment: @GuerricP Do parsing and loading mean the same thing?

Comment: Yes it's the same thing

Comment: @GuerricP See if I'm right here. Imagine '1' and '2' have no imports. Imagine 2 is placed before 1 in the source order. Also, imagine ‘A’ imports from ‘B’ which imports from ‘C’. The browser will first load|execute ‘2’ then ‘1’ (because they’re leaf modules and ‘2’ comes before ‘1’ in source order). Then it’ll load/execute ‘C’ because ‘B’ relies on ‘C’. Then it'll execute ‘B’ and then execute 'A'. Basically, the browser is clever enough to load the modules that other modules rely on, first. Would ‘1’ & '2' be the leaves, and ‘A’ through to ‘C’ be the branch that extends down to the root?

Comment: How are the numbers related to the letters in your example?

Comment: I was thinking of just a fresh example just to capture when modules are executed. Imagine 1, 2, A, B, C are all modules.

Comment: Well yes I think you got it, here is another way to conceive this: a module won't execute unless all of its dependencies (modules it imports) were already executed

Comment: Yes that's a much better way to put it. Great! If I may ask just one more thing. I imagine modules with the `async` attribute that import and export from each other might add a further complication. What's the situation here?

Comment: That aside, I've also thought of another complication. Fresh example - imagine modules A and B both export and import each other. Which one gets executed first? I've tested this and my hypothesis was that it would be the module that appears first in source-order. It was actually the inverse - the one latest in the source order executed first. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. 1. If the only thing that's guranteed is that which imports from a module can't execute before the module, why do so many articles say the statement: 'defer scripts are guaranteed to execute in the order that they appear in the document.' 2. I didn't quite understand your last paragraph. It seems like, for files with `async`, they'll try to execute asap but won't violate aforementioned rule.

Comment: The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts so what you read about deferred script is true, but it only applies to regular scripts. I think you understood the last paragraph, your interpretation sounds good to me.

Comment: I'm worried we can't control always control which module executes first, like in the examples in my question. Do I (generally) not need to worry because the modules execute very fast? For example, it's okay for a `setTimeout` to occur on a 5th (last) module as the time to execute the first 4 modules will be negligible? Also, what do you mean about regular scripts? Are they different to modules in terms of the rules that determine the order of their execution? And if so, how? (Fair enough if that question is worth putting on a new question).

Comment: Can you give an example where the order of execution matters? According to me if you want a specific execution order just dont use ES6 modules at all and put `script` tags in the desired order.

Comment: Imagine I have a `setTimeOut` on a fifth module. I don't want to wait long before its callback is executed. I presume the time to execute the first 4 modules will be so quick it shouldn't matter? Would you be able to point out where I could learn how the order of execution of scripts (not modules) is determined?

Comment: The order of execution of regular scripts (with no `type` attribute) is simply the `<script>` tags order

Comment: Is that because regular scripts can't do export imports with one another?

Comment: Exactly, a dependency between two regular scripts translates as follows: the dependency script mutates the global state, a dependent script uses that mutated global state. Example: jQuery will mutate the global state by creating a global `$` and all `script` tags that use it will fail if declared before the jQuery `script`

Comment: Thanks. And finally, for modules that don't do import & exports with one another - we can or cannot guarantee that they will execute in the order they appear in?

Comment: If they don't import and export each other, they're not module scripts, they are regular scripts and they execute in the `<script>` tags order as I said before. Don't forget to remove `type="module"`