# Does it matter that we can't easily predict the exact order that modules will execute in?

Tags: javascript

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417112/what-really-determines-the-order-javascript-modules-are-executed-in-the-html) I've become aware, for modules (not regular scripts & without `async` attribute) that import/export (from each other), one of the only simple rules that determines the order in which they're executed is that a module that imports from another module will not execute before the module it imports from.

I'm worried we can't always control the complete order in which modules execute (I've put some examples of this at the bottom of the post). For example, what if I want a timeout to start as soon as the page is loaded? Is it okay for a `setTimeout` to occur on a module (at the end of a very long list of modules) as the time to execute the initial modules will be negligible?

P.s. Am I safe to assume modules that don't import or export (from each other) always execute in the order they appear in?

---

Examples: ModuleA imports from ModuleB. ModuleC imports from ModuleD. Only rule is that D or B executes first (sometimes DB or BD executes first; sometimes DC or BA executes first).

Comment: A `setTimeout` or asynchronous call cannot interrupt already executing synchronous code

Comment: @Phil My question was more: will it take a long time for the last module, at the end of a very long list of modules, to execute? (Thanks for the response, I've edited my question to make this more clear).

Comment: Yes, in general modules should be executed pretty quickly as far as they're not doing heavy initialisation work. But it's really unclear what you are worrying about here. Could there be a "wrong" order for your modules in which they wouldn't work?

Comment: @Bergi No I wasn't worried about that, just trying to anticipate any problematic scenarios that'd occur as a result of not having complete control over the order modules that import|export (from one another) execute. I've re-edited the question to make it clear the problematic scenario I was thinking of. Although if modules do execute pretty quickly, as I suspected, it shouldn't be a problematic scenario.

Comment: "*What if I want a timeout to start as soon as the page is loaded.*" - for that, the order of module execution does absolutely not matter. What would make the timing unpredictable is the loading time of the modules, especially with different dependency tree shapes.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. So order of module execution doesn't matter because modules execute so fast the timer will start pretty much immediately? What do you mean in your second sentence?

Comment: I mean that for any external dependency, http loading time will dominate the execution time.

Comment: @Bergi Can I just confirm that order of module execution doesn't matter because modules execute so fast the timer will start pretty much immediately?

Answer (score 1):

I personally find that **assuming** something will happen before something else without enforcing that explicitly will result in a dangerous situation. Even if your modules would always execute in the correct order, you have created an implicit dependency between two modules that will make the code more difficult understand.

Will another developer working on your project be able to understand that certain modules need to execute first? Will you remember this when you revisit this code a few months down the line? What about when you leave the project and someone else inherits it?

Working on code like this can create spaghetti situations where making a change in one place creates cascading changes in other, unexpected places.

Alleviating this can really depend on what framework you're using, or if you're not using any framework at all. If you need certain dependencies loaded before executing certain code, use a dependency loader to ensure that dependencies are always available when they are needed. If you need a certain function to be executed before executing a function in a different module, create an event system. Redux/flux and Ngrx are really nice solutions for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nathan. Have bookmarked your post to get back to if I run into these types of problems in the future!